# How to get X, Y coordinates of the pixel depths in Kinect?

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I have a Bitmap, and coordinates on it. And there depthData array, filled only by the values of depth.

How do I get the depth of the pixel in the coordinates X, Y Bitmap?

For example: I have a rectangle, and its coordinates. How do I get deep inside reсtangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developing in the Kinect v2, I use the code below to get the x,y values.
desc is the DepthFrameDescription.

```
var x = i % (int)desc.Width;
var y = i / (int)desc.Width;
```

Hope this could help you.